# How can I send multiple images in a server push Perl CGI program?

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi, server-push

I am a beginner in Perl CGI etc. I was experimenting with server-push concept with a piece of Perl code. It is supposed to send a jpeg image to the client every three seconds.

Unfortunately nothing seems to work. Can somebody help identify the problem?

Here is the code:

```
use strict;
# turn off io buffering
$|=1;
print "Content-type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;";
print "boundary=magicalboundarystring\n\n";
print "--magicalboundarystring\n";

#list the jpg images
my(@file_list) = glob "*.jpg";
my($file) = "";

foreach $file(@file_list ) 
{
     open FILE,">", $file or die "Cannot open file $file: $!";
     print "Content-type: image/jpeg\n\n";

    while ( <FILE> )
    { 
        print "$_";
    }

    close FILE;
     print "\n--magicalboundarystring\n";
     sleep 3;
    next;

}
```

EDIT: added turn off i/o buffering, added "use strict" and "@file_list", "$file" are made local

Comment: First use strict and warnings. Next: Any error you can see?, Also, you open $file for read or write?

Comment: @Octopus No error in the log file nor the browser, just that the image  is not displayed. The loop seems to work fine. $file is opened for read.

Comment: Thats why i suggested to use strict and warnings:).

Comment: @ Octopus Added the "use strict", it gave couple of errors with variable declaration. I corrected them, but still the result is same.

Comment: Ok I'm just going to say what Octopus hinted at - $file is opened for writing not reading -- reverse the ">" to open it for reading. Also, can you even print an image like that? by iterating through each line in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flush the output.

Most probably, the server is keeping the response in the buffer. You may want to do `fflush(STDOUT)` after every `print` or `autoflush STDOUT` once.

Have a look at http://www.abiglime.com/webmaster/articles/cgi/032498.htm

[quote]

> To use the script below, you'll need
>   to implement a called "non-parsed"
>   CGIs on your site. Normally, the web
>   server will buffer all output from
>   your CGI program until it the program
>   finishes. We don't want that to happen
>   here. With Apache, it's quite easy. If
>   the name of your CGI program starts
>   with "nph-" it won't be parsed. Also,
>   change the glob "/some/path/*" to the
>   path where you want to look for files.

[/quote]

Comment: @Gaurav I've turned off the i/o buffering. But still same result :(

Comment: Have a look at the response on the console and see what do you get.

On firefox, try using Firebug; for IE use Fiddler.